# javafx TableView left justify single column

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

I've got a tableview of floats which work fine. I've made it so the cells are editable, formatted for currency etc. All the cells are right-justified as one would expect a numerical field to be.

One of the columns references a string (instead of a float), which is also editable-- that works too, using the `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` method. 
However I can't figure out how to left-justify the string -- it is right justified like the other columns. I tried using the `.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT)` method, but ***it only left-justifies when the cell is being edited***. After editing, it is right-justified again...

Here's the snippet for that particular column:

```
 cargoTableTypeCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<CargoItem, String> p) -> {
     TableCell<CargoItem, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
     cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
     return cell;
 });
 cargoTableTypeCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
 cargoTableTypeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().typeProperty());
```

And here's what it looks like:
[image]

as you can see the cell with "coal" in it is not left-justified. 
Iknow it's trivial, but frustrating nonetheless.

Comment: You set the cell factory twice, so the first factory you pass will have no effect.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up James. So how would I integrate the`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` (for editing) with the `setAlignment()` method (for formatting the edited value)?

Comment: Added an answer. In this particular use case, I would recommend using CSS, as in @UgurcanYildirim's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to try the following: `cargoTableTypeCol.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-LEFT;");`

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS, as in @UgurcanYildirim's answer (or using an external style sheet), is the best solution for this particular use case.

The reason the code in the question does not work is that the `cellFactory` is a property and follows the usual rules for properties. In particular, if you call `setCellFactory(...)` with one value and subsequently call it with a different value, the second value replaces the first, and the first is discarded. In other words, a `TableColumn` has one and only one `cellFactory`.

For a use case where you genuinely need to modify the cell returned by one cell factory, you can use the following (essentially just a decorator pattern):

```
Callback<TableColumn<CargoItem, String>, TableCell<CargoItem, String>> defaultCellFactory
    = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn();

cargoTableTypeCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TableCell<CargoItem, String> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(col);
    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    return cell ;
});
```